# Putting multiple lines of text opposite an image HTML

Tags: html, alignment

I've got several lines of text and links. I've got an image. I would like the text to be on the left and the image on the far right, but next to the text.

I used flexblocks to align the whole thing centre but that made the lines of text sit next to each other rather than one beneath the other which is not useful.

As you can probably tell, I'm new at this, so please word things simply, especially regarding CSS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap all your text lines in a single container such as a `<div>`, they will no longer be positioned next to each other. This is because now flexbox treats your text as a whole instead of every line individually. For example, change this:

```html
  <p>Line one</p>
  <br />
  <p>Line two</p>
```

to this:

```html
<div>
  <p>Line one</p>
  <br />
  <p>Line two</p>
</div>
```